# Python HTTP Request Patch

Tags: python, json, urllib2, patch

I'm trying to send information to the api via patch:

```
url = "http://xyz"

data_json = "{'estampas': [{'estampa': u'52'}, {'estampa': u'63'}, {'estampa': u'74'}, {'estampa': u'85'}, {'estampa': u'93'}, {'estampa': u'94'}, {'estampa': u'95'}, {'estampa': u'96'}, {'estampa': u'97'}, {'estampa': u'53'}, {'estampa': u'54'}, {'estampa': u'55'}, {'estampa': u'56'}, {'estampa': u'57'}, {'estampa': u'58'}, {'estampa': u'11'}]}"

request = urllib2.Request(url, data=urllib.urlencode(data_json))
request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
request.get_method = lambda: "PATCH"
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
print response
```

why print it?

```
<addinfourl at 140636007575424 whose fp = <httplib.HTTPResponse instance at 0x7fe85f462ab8>>
```

Comment: try `response.read()`. You are printing the  `HTTPResponse` object/reference

Comment: `{"error":{"code":400,"message":{"lang":"en-us","value":"Bad request: Unexpected character at position 0 - estampas=%5B%7B%27es"}}}`

Comment: Your json is not valid, you need double quotes `'{"estampas": [{"estampa": "52"}, {"estampa": "63"}, {"estampa": "74"}, {"estampa": "85"}, {"estampa": "93"}, {"estampa": "94"}, {"estampa": "95"}, {"estampa": "96"}, {"estampa": "97"}, {"estampa": "53"}, {"estampa": "54"}, {"estampa": "55"}, {"estampa": "56"}, {"estampa": "57"}, {"estampa": "58"}, {"estampa": "11"}]}'`

Comment: Also `urllib.urlencode(data_json)` should fail with an error using it on a string so not sure how you even get that far

Comment: worked, thank you very much!

Comment: No worries, you're welcome.

Comment: I will try, thank you

Comment: `data_json = {"estampas": []}

for moldura in molduras:
cod_estampa_millennium = moldura[0]
data_json["estampas"].append({"estampa": cod_estampa_millennium})`

already exists double quotes!

Comment: You might find that requests makes your life a lot simpler http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.patch

Comment: `{"estampas": [{"estampa": "52"}, {"estampa": "63"}, {"estampa": "74"}, {"estampa": "85"}, {"estampa": "93"}, {"estampa": "94"}, {"estampa": "95"}, {"estampa": "96"}, {"estampa": "97"}, {"estampa": "53"}, {"estampa": "54"}, {"estampa": "55"}, {"estampa": "56"}, {"estampa": "57"}, {"estampa": "58"}, {"estampa": "11"}]}`

Comment: {"error":{"code":400,"message":{"lang":"en-us","value":"Bad request: Unexpected character at position 0 - estampas=%5B%7B%27es"}}}

Comment: did you try using the requests library?

Comment: how using?

`class mydict(dict):
        def __str__(self):
            return json.dumps(self)

data_json = {"estampas": []}

query = "select cod_estampa_millennium from millennium_grupo_moldura"
con.cursor.execute(query)
molduras = con.cursor.fetchall()

for moldura in molduras:
    cod_estampa_millennium = moldura[0]
    data_json["estampas"].append({"estampa": cod_estampa_millennium})

data_json = mydict(data_json)

print data_json

odata.patch(data_json=data_json, param="8084")`